# in non-webkit browsers, the alignment of this div is off. What non-standard thing am I doing to cause this?

Tags: css, position, positioning, alignment

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xk9Wd/4/

Looks like this in webkit:
[image]

Looks like this in All non-webkit browsers:
[image]

Notice how in the image showing the non-webkit browsers, there is a empty space between the box and the right border.
The gray box that is misaligned here is positioned using `absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;`

And since it only "appears" correct in webkit browsers, I'm gessing there is something wrong with my markup.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set the

```
.properties-main { display: table-cell }
```

instead of

```
.properties-main { display: table }
```